# Can someone help me find the error in my Payday 2 mod?

Tags: lua

i tried to write a mod for payday 2, together in use with another mod so the strings in the hud are right.

this is the code:

```
Hooks:Add("LocalizationManagerPostInit", "Hold To Press", function(loc) --Change 'YOUR_MOD_NAME' to something else.
    LocalizationManager:add_localized_strings({
        hud_int_enter_code = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to enter the code",
        hud_int_hold_disassemble_turret = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to disassemble turret",
        hud_int_hold_ignite_money = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to ignite the money",
        hud_int_hold_cut_tree = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to cut the tree",
        hud_int_equipment_saw_upgrade = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to upgrade the saw",
        hud_int_hold_barcode = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the barcode",
        hud_unpack_turret = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to unpack the sentry gun",
        hud_fill_watertank = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to fill the water tank",
        hud_int_hold_born_untie = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to untie",
        hud_int_equipment_shaped_charge = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to use a shaped charge",
        hud_int_place_harddrive = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to place the hard drive",
        hud_hold_scan_hand = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to scan hand",
        hud_int_take_bridge = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to pick up the metal sheet",
        hud_int_hold_bag_sa_armor = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to bag a piece of samurai armor",
        hud_int_hold_search_documents = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search documents",
        hud_int_press_take_chimichanga = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the chimichanga",
        hud_int_take_missing_animal_poster = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take missing animal poster",
        hud_int_hack_timelock = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to force time lock",
        hud_int_hold_unlock_display_zeus = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to unlock zeus",
        hud_int_hold_remove_debris = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to remove debris",
        hud_cas_ignite_fireworks = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to ignite the fireworks",
        hud_int_hold_phone_office = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to call the office",
        hud_int_hold_cut_wires = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to cut wires",
        hud_int_hold_place_laptop = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to place the laptop",
        hud_int_search_steel_cabinet = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search steel cabinet",
        hud_int_equipment_drill_upgrade = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to upgrade the drill",
        hud_int_search_cigar_boxes = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search the cigar boxes",
        hud_int_hold_close_crate = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to close shipping crate",
        hud_int_close_window = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to close window",
        hud_int_hold_take_wrench = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take wrench",
        hud_int_hold_open_circuitbreaker = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open the circuit breaker box",
        hud_int_hold_add_blade = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to add the saw blade",
        hud_int_equipment_huge_lance_jammed = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to fix the Beast",
        hud_int_open_slash_close = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open",
        hud_int_open_panicroom = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to swipe the keycard",
        hud_int_take_ticket = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take ticket",
        hud_int_hold_take_blood_valid_sample = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the valid blood sample",
        hud_int_hold_search_c4 = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search for C4",
        hud_int_hold_activate_sprinklers = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to activate sprinklers",
        hud_int_hold_cut_wire_blue = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to cut the blue wire",
        hud_place_watertank = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to place the water tank",
        hud_int_hold_take_blade = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the saw blade",
        hud_int_hold_take_helmet = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take BCI Helmet",
        hud_int_search_cabinet = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search cabinet",
        hud_cas_take_fireworks_bag = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the fireworks",
        hud_int_hold_born_soda = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the soda",
        hud_connect_which_hook = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to connect the winch to the BFD",
        hud_int_vehicle_loot = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take loot from the vehicle",
        hud_int_tape_loop = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to apply camera loop",
        hud_int_hold_unlock_display_chronos = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to unlock chronos",
        hud_int_hold_remove_battery = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to remove battery",
        hud_int_hold_open_coke = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open yayo",
        hud_int_hold_take_pig = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take a Pig",
        hud_hold_remove_screw = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to remove the screw",
        hud_int_search_shower = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search shower",
        hud_int_hold_search_dumpster = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search the dumpster",
        hud_man_apply_tape = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to apply tape",
        hud_int_hold_approve_request = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to approve request",
        hud_int_hold_open_vault = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open the vault",
        hud_int_hold_activate_reader = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to activate the barcode reader",
        hud_int_open_cargo_door = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open cargo door",
        hud_hold_open_bomb_hatch = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open bomb hatch",
        hud_int_hold_detach_hose = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to detach hose",
        hud_int_hold_connect_equip = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to connect the equipment",
        hud_int_hold_open_hatch = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open hatch",
        hud_int_take_diamonds_dah = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take diamonds",
        hud_int_hold_open_shopping_bag = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open shopping bag",
        hud_int_equipment_drill = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to use the drill",
        hud_int_hold_search_clues = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search for clues",
        hud_int_hold_take_meth = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the meth",
        hud_int_hold_add_compound_c = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to add compound c",
        hud_int_methlab_gas_to_salt = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to add the hydrogen chloride",
        hud_int_hold_hack_computer = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to hack the computer",
        hud_int_hold_ignite_trap = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to ignite the trap",
        hud_cas_security_door = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to pick the lock",
        hud_connect_cable = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to connect the cable to the power socket",
        hud_int_hold_open_display = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open display",
        hud_take_briefcase = "Press $BTN_INTERACT;  take the briefcase",
        hud_int_hold_pku_equipment = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to grab the equipment",
        hud_interact_pickup_sentry_gun = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to pick up.$NL; $AMMO_LEFT;% ammo left.",
        hud_int_remove_rope = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to remove rope",
        hud_int_hold_pull_switch = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to pull switch",
        hud_int_hold_activate_camera = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to place the camera",
        hud_int_big_computer_hackable = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to hack computer",
        hud_int_take_harddrive = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the hard drive",
        hud_int_hold_remove_liquid_nitrogen = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to remove liquid nitrogen",
        hud_disable_lasers = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to disable the lasers",
        hud_int_hold_pku_briefcase = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to pick up the briefcase",
        hud_int_hold_cut_cable = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to cut the cable",
        hud_int_hold_turn_off_light = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to turn off the lights",
        hud_int_hold_pick_up = "hold $BTN_INTERACT; to pick up",
        hud_int_hold_remove_painting = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to remove painting",
        hud_int_hold_to_help_turtle = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to help the turtle get back up",
        hud_int_hold_open_lid = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open lid",
        hud_int_hold_add_compound_b = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to add compound b",
        hud_int_rewire_box = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to rewire",
        hud_int_use_ticket = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to use ticket",
        hud_int_fire_missiles = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to fire missiles",
        hud_int_hold_connect_hose = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to connect the hose",
        hud_int_hold_moon_attach_winch = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to attach the winch",
        hud_int_hold_extinguish_fire = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to extinguish fire",
        hud_int_hack_laptop = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to hack the laptop",
        hud_int_search_files = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search for the files",
        hud_int_hold_grab_the_painting = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to grab the painting",
        hud_hack_ship_control = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to hack the ship control terminal",
        hud_int_hold_take_necklace = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take diamond necklace",
        hud_int_hold_pickup_lance = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to grab the thermal drill",
        hud_int_hold_take_paper_roll = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the paper roll",
        hud_hold_turn_of_gas = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to turn off gas",
        hud_int_hold_take_handcuffs = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take handcuffs",
        hud_int_grab_code = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to grab the code",
        hud_int_take_red_diamond = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take red diamond",
        hud_int_hold_download_keys = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to download encryption keys",
        hud_int_hold_check_evidence = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to check the evidence",
        hud_connect_which_hook_brb = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to connect the winch to the vault",
        hud_int_hold_pickup_boards = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to pick up boards",
        hud_int_hold_born_receive_item_blow_torch = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the blowtorch",
        hud_int_hold_hand_over_chrome_skull = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to hand over the chrome skull",
        hud_int_hold_grab_the_bag = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to grab the bag",
        hud_int_hold_scan_blueprints = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to scan the blueprints",
        hud_int_hold_take_safe = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the safe",
        hud_int_hold_take_pills = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the Pills",
        hud_int_hold_ignite_concoction = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to ignite the concoction",
        hud_int_hold_start_crane = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to start the crane",
        hud_open_cas_securityroom_door = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open the Security Center door",
        hud_int_hold_take_wine = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the wine",
        hud_int_hold_answer_call = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to answer call",
        hud_int_open_window = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open window",
        hud_int_hold_rewire_fuse_box = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to rewire the security barrier",
        hud_int_hold_grab_parachute = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to grab the parachute",
        hud_int_dispose_corpse = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to bag the corpse",
        hud_int_driving_drive = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to enter vehicle",
        hud_int_hold_take_expensive_wine = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take expensive wine",
        hud_int_hold_take_concoction = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the concoction",
        hud_int_hold_breach = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to breach",
        hud_int_hold_insert_plates = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to insert printing plates",
        hud_int_hold_take_cocaine = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the cocaine",
        hud_start_winch = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to start the winch",
        hud_int_hold_open_slash_close_sec_box = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open/close security box",
        hud_int_hold_born_search_tools = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search for tools",
        hud_int_hold_pull_lever = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to pull the lever",
        hud_int_keyboard_hox_1 = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to lower bollards",
        hud_int_hack_box = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to hack electrical box",
        hud_hold_start_scanning = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to activate the scanner",
        hud_int_hold_cut_fence = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to cut the fence",
        hud_int_use_ecm_jammer = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to use the ECM jammer",
        hud_int_rewire_timelock = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to re-wire the time lock",
        hud_int_hold_search_toilet = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search the portable toilet",
        hud_int_hold_take_warhead = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the warhead",
        hud_int_hold_aim_laser = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to aim laser",
        hud_int_hold_pick_up_turtle = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to pick the turtle up",
        hold_interact_charge_gun = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to start charging the laser",
        hud_int_old_wine = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take old wine",
        hud_int_hold_pku_breaching_charges = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to pickup breaching charges",
        hud_move_ship_gps_coords = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to enter new GPS coordinates",
        hud_int_equipment_huge_lance = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to use the Beast",
        hud_int_hold_unlock_display_poseidon = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to unlock poseidon",
        hud_int_hold_ignite_thermite_paste = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to ignite the thermite paste",
        hud_int_hostage_convert = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to convert the enemy",
        hud_int_hold_take_toothbrush = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the toothbrush",
        hud_int_fork_lift_sound = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to start the fork lifter",
        hud_int_hold_remove_cover = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to remove the cover",
        hud_int_hold_place_breaching_detonator = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to place breaching detonator",
        hud_int_hold_take_pardons = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the pardon",
        hud_cas_open_guitar_case = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open the guitar case",
        hud_int_hold_take_saw = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the saw",
        hud_int_search_washer = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search washer",
        hud_born_plug_in_powercord = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to plug in the power",
        hud_int_search_fridge = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search fridge",
        hud_int_set_off_alarm = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to set off the alarm",
        hud_int_hold_grab_goat = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to grab the goat",
        hud_hold_start_bomb_charge = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to start charging bomb",
        hud_int_hold_jam_vent = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to jam the vent",
        hud_int_hold_take_gas = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the gasoline",
        hud_int_hack_server_room = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to hack laptop",
        hud_int_hold_take_yayo = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the yayo",
        hud_int_hold_unlock_display_hades = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to unlock hades",
        hud_int_hold_unlock_display_demeter = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to unlock demeter",
        hud_int_hold_release_hatch = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to release hatch",
        hud_int_hold_relay_locke = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to relay Locke",
        hud_int_hold_take_counterfeit_money = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the Counterfeit money",
        hud_check_customer_database = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to download guest list",
        hud_place_sleeping_gass = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to pump gas into the vent",
        hud_int_hold_cut_tarp = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to cut open the tarp",
        hud_man_remove_bars = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to apply tape",
        hud_int_hold_insert_paper_roll = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to insert the paper roll",
        hud_int_search_display_case = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search display case",
        hud_int_hold_open_door = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open the door",
        hud_int_search_luggage = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search luggage",
        hud_int_hold_turn_on_power = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to Turn on the Power",
        hud_int_hold_open_xmas_present = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open Xmas present",
        hud_hold_burn_offshore_money = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to burn all your offshore money",
        hud_int_hold_to_choose_mask = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to choose mask",
        hud_int_hold_take_server = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the server",
        hud_int_assemble_device = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to assemble",
        hud_int_hold_disarm_bomb = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to disarm the bomb",
        hud_int_type_in_password = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to type in password",
        hud_cas_take_gear = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take your gear",
        hud_int_hold_roll_carpet = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to roll the carpet",
        hud_int_equipment_lance = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to use the thermal drill",
        hud_int_vehicle_repair = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to repair the vehicle",
        hud_cas_open_powerbox = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to pick the powerbox lock",
        hud_hack_skylight_barrier = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to hack the skylight barrier",
        hud_generator_start = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to start the generator",
        hud_fix_bfd_drill = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to fix the BFD",
        hud_hold_bet_slotmachine_chl = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to play the slots ($10,000)",
        hud_hold_removing_hand = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to remove hand",
        hud_int_big_computer_server = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to remotely access computer",
        hud_int_break_planks = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to break the planks",
        hud_int_cut_glass = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to cut glass",
        hud_int_disable_alarm_pager = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to answer the pager",
        hud_int_equipment_drill_jammed = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to restart the drill",
        hud_int_equipment_lance_jammed = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to reignite the thermal drill",
        hud_int_equipment_lance_upgrade = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to upgrade the thermal drill",
        hud_int_exit_to_crimenet = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to exit to Crime.net",
        hud_int_grab_server = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the server",
        hud_int_hold_add_compound_a = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to add compound a",
        hud_int_hold_add_compound_d = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to add compound d",
        hud_int_hold_analyze_evidence = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to analyze evidence",
        hud_int_hold_assemble_thermite = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to assemble thermite rig",
        hud_int_hold_attach_magnet = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to attach magnet",
        hud_int_hold_bag_present = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to bag the present",
        hud_int_hold_born_ride_the_bike = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to ride the bike",
        hud_int_hold_born_take_bike_part = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the bike part",
        hud_int_hold_bypass_firewall = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to bypass firewall",
        hud_int_hold_call_captain = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to call the captain",
        hud_int_hold_check_file = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to check file",
        hud_int_hold_crack_crate = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open shipping crate",
        hud_int_hold_cut = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to cut",
        hud_int_hold_disable_alarm = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to disable the alarm",
        hud_int_hold_disassemble_cro_loot = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the bomb part",
        hud_int_hold_fasten_strap = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to fasten the strap",
        hud_int_hold_gather_evidence = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to gather evidence",
        hud_int_hold_grab_body = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to grab the body",
        hud_int_hold_hack_barrier = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to hack the security barrier",
        hud_int_hold_hack_numpad = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to hack the numpad",
        hud_int_hold_ignite_thermite = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to ignite the thermite",
        hud_int_hold_insert_printer_ink = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to insert printer ink",
        hud_int_hold_insert_usb = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to insert the usb",
        hud_int_hold_mix_concoction = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to mix compounds",
        hud_int_hold_move_car = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to move the car",
        hud_int_hold_move_crane = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to move the crane",
        hud_int_hold_open_case = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open the case",
        hud_int_hold_open_safe = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open the safe",
        hud_int_hold_open_vent = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open the vent",
        hud_int_hold_pack_shells = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to pack Shells",
        hud_int_hold_pku_knife = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to Pick up the Knife",
        hud_int_hold_pku_uno_gold = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; take mayan gold",
        hud_int_hold_place_breaching_detonator_rearm = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to re-arm breaching detonator",
        hud_int_hold_place_gps_tracker = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to place the gps tracker",
        hud_int_hold_place_liquid_nitrogen = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to place liquid nitrogen",
        hud_int_hold_plant_breaching_charge = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to plant breaching charge",
        hud_int_hold_play_slots = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to play the slots",
        hud_int_hold_poison_bottle = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to spike the bottle",
        hud_int_hold_postpone_update = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to postpone the update",
        hud_int_hold_raise_balloon = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to raise balloon",
        hud_int_hold_read_barcode = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to read the barcode",
        hud_int_hold_reboot = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to reboot the computer",
        hud_int_hold_remove_armor_plating = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to remove armor plating",
        hud_int_hold_remove_ladder = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to remove the ladder",
        hud_int_hold_remove_parts = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to move the parts",
        hud_int_hold_repair_wheel = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to repair the wheel",
        hud_int_hold_resume_upload = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to resume upload",
        hud_int_hold_search_books = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search",
        hud_int_hold_search_computer = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search the database",
        hud_int_hold_signal_mr_blonde = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to signal Mr. Blonde",
        hud_int_hold_start_hack = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to start hacking",
        hud_int_hold_start_motor = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to start the engine",
        hud_int_hold_start_new_hack = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to start a new hack",
        hud_int_hold_start_printer = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to start the printer",
        hud_int_hold_stash_vial = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to stash the vial",
        hud_int_hold_steal_meth = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to steal back the meth",
        hud_int_hold_take_artifact = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the artifact",
        hud_int_hold_take_battery = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take battery",
        hud_int_hold_take_blood_sample = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the blood sample",
        hud_int_hold_take_blow_torch = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the blow torch",
        hud_int_hold_take_blueprints = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the blueprints",
        hud_int_hold_take_box = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the box",
        hud_int_hold_take_circle_cutter = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the circle cutter",
        hud_int_hold_take_compound_a = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take compound a",
        hud_int_hold_take_compound_b = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take compound b",
        hud_int_hold_take_compound_c = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take compound c",
        hud_int_hold_take_compound_d = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take compound d",
        hud_int_hold_take_diamond_briefcase = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the diamond briefcase",
        hud_int_hold_take_evidence = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to bag the evidence",
        hud_int_hold_take_fire_extinguisher = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the fire extinguisher",
        hud_int_hold_take_hdd = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the Hard Drive",
        hud_int_hold_take_jewelry = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the jewelry",
        hud_int_hold_take_mask = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the mask",
        hud_int_hold_take_medallion = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the medallion",
        hud_int_hold_take_painting = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the painting",
        hud_int_hold_take_prototype = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take prototype",
        hud_int_hold_take_pure_cocaine = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take pure Colombian cocaine",
        hud_int_hold_take_reaktor = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the fusion reactor prototype",
        hud_int_hold_take_sandwich = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take Almir's toast",
        hud_int_hold_take_shoes = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take high heels",
        hud_int_hold_take_toy = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the Tin Boy toy",
        hud_int_hold_take_vr_headset = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take vr headset",
        hud_int_hold_to_place_device = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to place the device",
        hud_int_hold_to_take_tablet = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the tablet",
        hud_int_hold_unfold_ladder = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to unfold ladder",
        hud_int_hold_unlock_car = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to unlock the car",
        hud_int_hold_unlock_display_ares = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to unlock ares",
        hud_int_hold_use_computer = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to use the computer",
        hud_int_hold_use_device = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to place device",
        hud_int_invisible_interaction_close = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to close",
        hud_int_invisible_interaction_open = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open",
        hud_int_methlab_bubbling = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to add the muriatic acid",
        hud_int_methlab_caustic_cooler = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to add the caustic soda",
        hud_int_methlab_drying_meth = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to add the liquid meth",
        hud_int_move_gangplank = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to move gangplank",
        hud_int_pick_lock = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to pick the lock",
        hud_int_play_tape = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to play the tape",
        hud_int_press_place_chimichanga = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to place the chimichanga",
        hud_int_pry_open_elevator_door = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to pry open elevator door",
        hud_int_remove_stinger = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to remove police stinger",
        hud_int_search_blueprints = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search for the blueprints",
        hud_int_search_bookshelf = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search bookshelf",
        hud_int_search_capsule = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search capsule",
        hud_int_search_cart = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search cart",
        hud_int_search_case = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search case",
        hud_int_search_drawer = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search drawer",
        hud_int_search_drawers = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to search drawers",
        hud_int_setup_zipline = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to set up the zip-line",
        hud_int_set_up_sentry = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to set up the sentry gun",
        hud_int_shaped_sharge = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to place shaped charge",
        hud_int_signal_driver = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to signal the driver",
        hud_int_take_bottle = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to spike and pick up the bottle",
        hud_int_take_confidential_folder_event = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the address",
        hud_int_take_confidential_folder_icc = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the folder",
        hud_int_take_diamond = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take diamond",
        hud_int_take_plates = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to pickup printing plates",
        hud_int_take_thermite = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the thermite",
        hud_int_take_weapons = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the weapons",
        hud_int_try_keys = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to try a key",
        hud_int_turn_off = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to turn off",
        hud_int_use_bridge = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to bridge the gap",
        hud_int_use_computer = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the computer",
        hud_int_use_files = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to pass the files under the door",
        hud_int_vehicle_close_trunk = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to close the trunk",
        hud_int_vehicle_drive = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to drive the vehicle",
        hud_int_vehicle_enter = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to enter the vehicle",
        hud_int_vehicle_open_trunk = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open the trunk",
        hud_mil_hold_remove_bug = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to pick up recording device",
        hud_open_cas_briefcase = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to open the briefcase",
        hud_screw_down = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to screw the winch down",
        hud_start_drill = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to start the BFD",
        hud_stop_drill = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to stop the BFD",
        hud_take_??? = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take The Dentist's loot",
        hud_take_hook = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the hook",
        hud_take_sleeping_gas = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to pick up the sleeping gas",
        hud_take_watertank = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take the water tank"
    })
end)
```

well i ran into an issue where the logs responded with.

```
FATAL ERROR: (C:\Users\ZNix\source\repos\SuperBLT\src\InitiateState.cpp:294) mods\Hold To Press\htp.lua:351: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 2) near '?'
```

lua.org returned this.

```
input:27: unfinished string near <eof>
```

does someone have the soultion? i am new to coding and copied most of the script from the internet, just changing the string_id and what the string should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
        hud_take_??? = "Press $BTN_INTERACT; to take The Dentist's loot",
```

You can't have question marks in an unquoted key. Either rename that to something without question marks, or quote the key by replacing `hud_take_???` with `["hud_take_???"]` if you need to keep them.

Comment: thnx dude, gonna give it a go and ill give an update as soon as possible.

Comment: It still does not work in game, but it doest put more errors in the logs. putting the new code (Shortend) in https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo gives me this error: input:1: attempt to index a nil value (global 'Hooks')

Comment: @Niek - The `Hooks` exists only in the Lua in the game, it does not exist in standard Lua

Comment: good to know, but by using a bit of brainpower i already figured that out myself xD (i mean its called Hooks). but thnx anyway. also to solve the issue, ill just spread the strings out over a lot of file.